Jupyter Lab is inputting blank lines in the output for each suppressed line of code
I am using an octave kernel in Jupyter Labs. I have noticed a problem, where when I use a semicolon to suppress code from appearing in the output, it adds a blank line instead. This can make my documents quite long.
I have tried using %%capture, updating the octave kernel, and even uninstalling and reinstalling it. All of these produced no difference in my output.
enter image description here
enter image description here

Can you share examples and the specific kernel you are using? For example, I am not seeing the xeus-octave kernel, that I can use by following the link to try online from here, doesn't seem to act like the minimal working example here. As for %%capture, that comes from IPython, see here. As for %%capture, that comes from IPython, ...

  see here. So I wouldn't expect it to work in Octave. In fact ,I just tried it in a session where I referenced above with the Xeus-Octave kernel and it does nothing as expected. This is probably consistent with the fact % is a way to make a comment per here: "In the Octave language, a comment starts with either the sharp sign character, ‘#’, or the percent symbol ‘%’ and continues to the end of the line. Any text following the ...

 sharp sign or percent symbol is ignored by the Octave interpreter and not executed."  So syntax wise, the Octave kernel would probably use different symbols if it had magics involved. (I don't know if it is in XEUS-Octave, but there was an extension in IPython for adding magics, see here. The signal was %octave at the start of the line or %%octave in the cell. Here shows ipynb one.)

I did my best to add pictures to illustrate what I mean. The space between the code in the first picture and plot in the second picture is unwanted. If I put the plot command in its own code block, there is no space above the plot, but then the code block withe the function produces just white space. I did just install xeus-octave as you suggested, but that caused no changes.

I know in this case you were trying to illustrate a behavior, so an image is helpful, but sharing the code you show in the picture also as text is typical as well. Please see under 'Help others reproduce the problem' in How do I ask a good question?. I'm curious to explore if/why the function would be making a space when I didn't see it for the code here.

From the examples in the answer and replies here, I'd expect the ; after function xdot = f(x,t) in your screenshot to not be needed and may be causing an issue?

The ; didn't effect anything. To be honest, it was only there because I was trying to fix this issue before posting. Your advise to use xeux-octave instead of just octave worked. I just needed to remove the first line of code graphics_toolkit("gnuplot"); as well.

I was just trying to find a recent Octave kernel and that one came up as one that had a MyBinder offering that would allow testing it without needing to install. Glad it helped. It would seem to suggest it is kernel-specific thing and not related to JupyterLab per se, too.
